# Scripting language in android

Tags: android

I'm new to android.I have vbscript code that performs a certain task. I want to call this script from my activity. Is it possible to do so? Is it possible to call a shell script from an activity? I know that we can call C/C++ code from android, but can we call methods written in any other languages like PERL,Python from out activity?

Answer (score 2):

VBScript is a Microsoft language designed to run on Microsoft operating systems with Windows Scripting Host installed, so it won't work.

For your second question about the shell script, depending on what is in the shell script, it may or may not require root privileges.

Comment: Can we use a shell script?

Comment: @Anu I added something about it